# Contact Form 7 Validation is driving me nuts

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I've been trying for days now to implement validation on a series of forms in Wordpress using the Contact Form 7 plugin. It seems to be perennially popular and no-one else seems to be having the same issues that I am.

I need to have all of the inputs validating so I installed the jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7 plugin which includes email and others.

None of my forms validate correctly. The principal one is a simple call request form which is situated inside a modal, triggered via a link in the header. I wondered whether the modal was causing a problem so I created a test post with the form inside.

The errors appear when the fields are blank but the send button doesn't work at all. To compound this, there is another form in the sidebar and when this is completed and the submit button pressed, the validation errors on the OTHER form appear!

I really can't get my head around this at all. I've considered pulling all of the forms and writing them from scratch, implementing my own validation as I go along but it seems stupid to re-invent the wheel. I'd appreciate any assistance on this.

Sorry, forgot to include a link!

http://trustedlocalsuppliers.com/test-form/

Comment: Look into your browser’s error console!

Comment: I have looked at the console. There is an error stating: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: form.wpcf7-form" "
Looking at this means nothing to me though.

Comment: I get syntax errors before that, because your embedded JS code seems to contain `</p><p>` tags – looks like you have enbaled some kind of HTML processing for something that should simply be code instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help by the way @CBroe. So I stripped out an alternate form that I'd been trying but it's still not happy. I don't understand what the current error is telling me though.

Comment: Validating via jquery won't do you too much good anyway, if someone disables javascript they could easily bypass it.

Comment: I really don't get what the problem is here though. Surely 95% of the Wordpress sites out there just use a standard set of plugins? Why can it be so difficult to implement some pretty basic forms that require user input? I understand that jQuery will not provide the most robust method of validation but I can't even achieve that!

Answer (score 0):

I googled around as many others here, the problem is that CF7 changed it's code some time ago and you will find old examples. Here is a working example for CF7 Version 4.2 I use:

```
function custom_email_validation_filter($result, $tag) {     
    $tag = new WPCF7_Shortcode( $tag );
    $name = $tag->name;
    if($name == 'your-email') { // Only apply to fields with the form field name of "your-email"  
         $the_value = $_POST[$name];  
         if( (substr($the_value, -10) !== '@gmail.com') ) {  
              $result->invalidate($tag, "This is not a gmail address!");
         };  
    };  
    return $result;  
};
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email','custom_email_validation_filter', 10, 2); // Email field  
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_validation_filter', 10, 2); // Required Email field
```

That Example adds an additional "Gmail-Email-Address-Validator" to a field named "your-email". The last two lines hook the function right into the email-field (optional) and the email-field (non-optional) - both.

This easy to understand example is tested, works and hopefully saves your time :) - please vote :)
Working Example is here: https://www.baab.de/bestellung-wordpress-nginx-webhosting/